# Keyboard shortcut to select the address bar for the current page in Safari?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, safari

When I want to navigate to a new page using the address bar in Safari without taking my hands off the keyboard, I use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, which opens a new tab and places the cursor in its address bar.

This is fine when I want to keep the original page open in another tab. But sometimes I want to replace it with the new page. Sometimes I can get back to the address bar by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> several times, but the number of times depends on the amount of tab-selectable fields on the page.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to select the address bar for the current page in Safari?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> is the keyboard shortcut you are looking for.

This shortcut is corresponding to **Open Location...** command which can be found under File → Open Location... in Safari Menu bar.

Comment: Thanks! It's strange that this command doesn't appear on Apple's list of Safari keyboard shortcuts: https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/keyboard-and-other-shortcuts-cpsh003/mac

Comment: @Crowder It's called the Open Location command and can be found under File → Open Location..., with the keyboard shortcut Command + L.